# Swift: Optional dataSource with return type a struct

Tags: ios, swift, struct, protocols

I am trying to create an optional dataSource which will expect to receive a structure. So I did below.

```
struct Configuration {
    var color = UIColor.grayColor()
    var width: CGFloat = 10
}

@objc protocol CustomDataSource {
   optional func configuration() -> Configuration
}
```

but as the result type is not Objective-C type so it's throws an error like below.

[image]

I don't want to make this dataSource as required but if its been implement then it must return that structure. I can create custom class to do the same. But is it possible by structure?

Comment: See the link to the question I put above, I'm afraid it's not possible yet!!!

Comment: You can always return the properties of the struct and use the return to (attempt to) initialize a `Configuration` instance (using a failable initializer). In your simple example, e.g. return a dictionary with the single key entry holding the `UIColor` (hashable: ok) and the corresponding single value holding the `CGFloat`. E.g., [see this example](https://gist.github.com/dfrib/246261b9f03f6feaef1a).